# Gnome Keyring to Unlock on Login

Tags: ssh, arch-linux, gnome-keyring

I'm on Arch Linux. My gnome-keyring has the same password as my user account.

I want the gnome-keyring to unlock automatically on login. I am using WDM and ZSH. I have followed the steps outline in the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GNOME/Keyring).

In my `.zprofile` I have:

```
# initialising gnome keyring
if [ -n "$DESKTOP_SESSION" ];then
  eval $(gnome-keyring-daemon --start)
  export SSH_AUTH_SOCK
fi
```

And inside `/etc/pam.d/login` I have:

```
#%PAM-1.0

auth       required     pam_securetty.so
auth       requisite    pam_nologin.so
auth       include      system-local-login
auth       optional     pam_gnome_keyring.so
account    include      system-local-login
session    include      system-local-login
session    optional     pam_gnome_keyring.so auto_start
password   include      system-local-login
```

Yet still, the keyring remains locked once I log in.

The journal has the following:

```
~ ❯ journalctl -b | grep "keyring"
Jul 30 22:35:31 desktop kernel: Initialise system trusted keyrings
Jul 30 22:35:37 desktop audit[354]: USER_AUTH pid=354 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='op=PAM:authentication grantors=pam_securetty,pam_shells,pam_faillock,pam_permit,pam_faillock,pam_gnome_keyring acct="j" exe="/usr/bin/login" hostname=desktop addr=? terminal=/dev/tty1 res=success'
Jul 30 22:35:37 desktop audit[354]: CRED_ACQ pid=354 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='op=PAM:setcred grantors=pam_securetty,pam_shells,pam_faillock,pam_permit,pam_faillock,pam_gnome_keyring acct="j" exe="/usr/bin/login" hostname=desktop addr=? terminal=/dev/tty1 res=success'
Jul 30 22:35:37 desktop audit[354]: USER_START pid=354 uid=0 auid=1000 ses=1 msg='op=PAM:session_open grantors=pam_loginuid,pam_keyinit,pam_limits,pam_unix,pam_permit,pam_mail,pam_systemd,pam_env,pam_gnome_keyring acct="j" exe="/usr/bin/login" hostname=desktop addr=? terminal=/dev/tty1 res=success'
Jul 30 22:35:37 desktop audit[354]: CRED_REFR pid=354 uid=0 auid=1000 ses=1 msg='op=PAM:setcred grantors=pam_securetty,pam_shells,pam_faillock,pam_permit,pam_faillock,pam_gnome_keyring acct="j" exe="/usr/bin/login" hostname=desktop addr=? terminal=/dev/tty1 res=success'
Jul 30 22:35:37 desktop login[354]: gkr-pam: gnome-keyring-daemon started properly and unlocked keyring
Jul 30 22:39:24 desktop gnome-keyring-daemon[1820]: couldn't access control socket: /run/user/1000/keyring/control: No such file or directory
Jul 30 22:39:24 desktop gnome-keyring-d[1820]: couldn't access control socket: /run/user/1000/keyring/control: No such file or directory
Jul 30 22:39:24 desktop gnome-keyring-daemon[1820]: no private keys found in file
Jul 30 22:39:24 desktop gnome-keyring-d[1820]: no private keys found in file
Jul 30 22:39:24 desktop gnome-keyring-daemon[1820]: invalid or unrecognized private SSH key: j@desktop
Jul 30 22:39:24 desktop gnome-keyring-d[1820]: invalid or unrecognized private SSH key: j@desktop
Jul 30 22:39:24 desktop gnome-keyring-daemon[1820]: no private keys found in file
Jul 30 22:39:24 desktop gnome-keyring-d[1820]: no private keys found in file
Jul 30 22:39:24 desktop gnome-keyring-daemon[1820]: invalid or unrecognized private SSH key: j@desktop
Jul 30 22:39:24 desktop gnome-keyring-d[1820]: invalid or unrecognized private SSH key: j@desktop
Jul 30 22:39:24 desktop gnome-keyring-daemon[1820]: no private key present for public key: /home/j/.ssh/AWSUbuntuKeyPairDavid.pub
Jul 30 22:39:24 desktop gnome-keyring-d[1820]: no private key present for public key: /home/j/.ssh/AWSUbuntuKeyPairDavid.pub
Jul 30 22:39:24 desktop gnome-keyring-daemon[1820]: no private keys found in file
Jul 30 22:39:24 desktop gnome-keyring-daemon[1820]: invalid or unrecognized private SSH key: j@desktop
Jul 30 22:39:24 desktop gnome-keyring-d[1820]: no private keys found in file
Jul 30 22:39:24 desktop gnome-keyring-d[1820]: invalid or unrecognized private SSH key: j@desktop
Jul 30 22:39:24 desktop dbus-daemon[662]: [session uid=1000 pid=662] Activating service name='org.gnome.keyring.SystemPrompter' requested by ':1.14' (uid=1000 pid=1820 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --start --foreground")
Jul 30 22:39:24 desktop gcr-prompter[1827]: Gcr: bus acquired: org.gnome.keyring.SystemPrompter
Jul 30 22:39:24 desktop gcr-prompter[1827]: Gcr: bus acquired: org.gnome.keyring.PrivatePrompter
Jul 30 22:39:24 desktop dbus-daemon[662]: [session uid=1000 pid=662] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.keyring.SystemPrompter'
Jul 30 22:39:24 desktop gcr-prompter[1827]: Gcr: acquired name: org.gnome.keyring.SystemPrompter
Jul 30 22:39:24 desktop gcr-prompter[1827]: Gcr: received BeginPrompting call from callback /org/gnome/keyring/Prompt/p2@:1.14
Jul 30 22:39:24 desktop gcr-prompter[1827]: Gcr: preparing a prompt for callback /org/gnome/keyring/Prompt/p2@:1.14
Jul 30 22:39:24 desktop gcr-prompter[1827]: Gcr: calling the PromptReady method on /org/gnome/keyring/Prompt/p2@:1.14
Jul 30 22:39:24 desktop gcr-prompter[1827]: Gcr: acquired name: org.gnome.keyring.PrivatePrompter
Jul 30 22:39:24 desktop gcr-prompter[1827]: Gcr: returned from the PromptReady method on /org/gnome/keyring/Prompt/p2@:1.14
Jul 30 22:39:24 desktop gcr-prompter[1827]: Gcr: received PerformPrompt call from callback /org/gnome/keyring/Prompt/p2@:1.14
Jul 30 22:39:24 desktop gcr-prompter[1827]: Gcr: starting password prompt for callback /org/gnome/keyring/Prompt/p2@:1.14
Jul 30 22:39:32 desktop gcr-prompter[1827]: Gcr: completed password prompt for callback :1.14@/org/gnome/keyring/Prompt/p2
Jul 30 22:39:32 desktop gcr-prompter[1827]: Gcr: calling the PromptReady method on /org/gnome/keyring/Prompt/p2@:1.14
Jul 30 22:39:32 desktop gcr-prompter[1827]: Gcr: returned from the PromptReady method on /org/gnome/keyring/Prompt/p2@:1.14
Jul 30 22:39:32 desktop gcr-prompter[1827]: Gcr: received PerformPrompt call from callback /org/gnome/keyring/Prompt/p2@:1.14
Jul 30 22:39:32 desktop gcr-prompter[1827]: Gcr: stopping prompting for operation /org/gnome/keyring/Prompt/p2@:1.14
Jul 30 22:39:32 desktop gcr-prompter[1827]: Gcr: stopping prompting for operation /org/gnome/keyring/Prompt/p2@:1.14
Jul 30 22:39:32 desktop gcr-prompter[1827]: Gcr: couldn't find the callback for prompting operation /org/gnome/keyring/Prompt/p2@:1.14
Jul 30 22:39:32 desktop gcr-prompter[1827]: Gcr: stopping prompting for operation /org/gnome/keyring/Prompt/p2@:1.14
Jul 30 22:39:32 desktop gcr-prompter[1827]: Gcr: couldn't find the callback for prompting operation /org/gnome/keyring/Prompt/p2@:1.14
Jul 30 22:39:32 desktop gcr-prompter[1827]: Gcr: stopping prompting for operation /org/gnome/keyring/Prompt/p2@:1.14
Jul 30 22:39:32 desktop gcr-prompter[1827]: Gcr: couldn't find the callback for prompting operation /org/gnome/keyring/Prompt/p2@:1.14
Jul 30 22:39:32 desktop gcr-prompter[1827]: Gcr: calling the PromptDone method on /org/gnome/keyring/Prompt/p2@:1.14, and ignoring reply
```

What am I missing?